# Renaming Queue in Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

Can we rename a Queue without deleting and recreating it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is not possible to rename a WebSphere MQ queue.  There are two options:

1. You can define an alias over an existing queue where the alias has the desired name.
2. You can define a new queue with the desired name and move any messages into it from the original queue.

In the event that you take the second option, there are a number of tools to move the messages.  Two of the more popular tools are mqmon from [SupportPac MO71](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000142&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) and the Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000647&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en).